# jQuery AJAX relation between success and .then

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to solve a very simple problem, but I can't figure it out.
I have following code:

```
<button onclick="run()">TEST</button>
<script>
    var counter = 0;
    function test() {           
        return $.ajax({
           url: "https://127.0.0.1:4432",
           success: function(html){
              console.log('success! test');
           },
           error: function() {
            if (counter++ < 3) {
                console.log("Retrying");
                $.ajax(this);
                return;
            }           
            console.log('ERROR! test');
           }
        });
    }   

    function run() {
        test()
        .then(
            function(){console.log('finished ALL OK')}, 
            function() {console.log('finished all ERROR')
        ;});

    }


</script>
```

What I want to achieve is that after clicking on the button, the AJAX request will be sent to server. In case of failure of the AJAX the request will be retried. Only after all retries will be finished, then the success or failure in the ".then" function will be called .

At this moment, the code behaves like that the AJAX call is retried three times, but the ".then()" handler is called right after first failure.

In console of the browser it looks like this:

[image: Console of the browser]

I would like to see the "finished all ERROR" text at the end after all retries.

Hope this makes sense and I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: The `.then()` function is called when the AJAX request completes, whether it succeeds or fails. If it succeeds the first callback is called, if it fails the second one is called. This is independent of calling the `success` or `error` callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever's in the `success` method won't affect the `.then` on the same jqXHR object. For the chaining you're looking for, consider using *only* `.then`s and `.catch`es instead:

```js
function test() {
  let counter = 0;
  const get = () => $.ajax({ url: "https://127.0.0.1:4432" })
  .then((html) => {
    console.log('success');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    if (counter++ < 3) {
      console.log("Retrying");
      return get();
    }
    console.log('ERROR! test');
    throw new Error();
  });
  return get();
}

test()
  .then(
  function() {
    console.log('finished ALL OK')
  },
  function() {
    console.log('finished all ERROR');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: clean and effective.

Comment: Thank you, this is correct solution for me. I only had to replace arrow functions with normal functions and I cannot use .catch method because I have to use jquery 1.9 and it must run in IE11. So thanks once again

Comment: If your script is of any reasonable size, I'd highly recommend integrating Babel and polyfills into your build process so that you can write, read, and debug code in the latest and greatest version of the language, and transpile it down to ES5 for production so that ancient browsers can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test(counter, $existingDeferred) {
        var $deferred = $existingDeferred || $.Deferred();
        
        $.ajax({
           url: "https://127.0.0.1:4432",
           success: function(html){
              console.log('success! test');
              $deferred.resolve(arguments);
           },
           error: function() {
            console.log('ERROR! test');
            
            if (counter < 3) {
                console.log("Retrying");
                test(++counter, $deferred);
            } else {
                $deferred.reject(arguments);
            }
          }
        });
        
        return $deferred;
    }   

    function run() {
        test(0)
        .then(
            function(){console.log('finished ALL OK')}, 
            function() {console.log('finished all ERROR')
        ;});

    }
```

You can make a secondary deferred that controls when the retry attempts are exausted.

- Pass in the counter count, and optionally the secondary deferred
- If we do not have an existing deferred, create one.

  - Perform the ajax request
  - If success, resolve the deferred
  - If error
  - If attempts have not been exausted, recurse the method with the counter incremented and the existing deferred
  - Otherwise, reject the deferred to signify the process end
- Return the deferred that will be resolved upon success, or rejected when all attempts are exausted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using recursion.

```js
function test(fn, retries) {
  return fn().catch(error => 
    retries > 0 ? test(fn, retries - 1) : Promise.reject(error)
  );
}

test(() => $.ajax({ url: "https://127.0.0.1:4432" }), 3)
  .then(data => console.log('finished ALL OK'))
  .catch(lastError => console.log('finished all ERROR'));
```

If `fn` is called with a successful response the `catch` is never called stopping the recursion. If `fn` doesn't have a positive response it checks if there are any retries left. If this is the case it calls `test` again with one less retry, if there are no retries left `Promise.reject` is called providing the last error.

**Note:** If you're not using jQuery version 3.0 or higher you'll have to replace `.catch(...)` with `.then(null, ...)`.

Answer (score -1):

one possible solution is to wrap your entire operation in a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), although you may need a polyfill for 100% browser support.  that would look something like this:

```js
function test() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var counter = 0;
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://127.0.0.1:4432",
            success: function(html){
                console.log('success! test');
                resolve(html);
            },
            error: function() {
                if (counter++ < 3) {
                    console.log("Retrying");
                    $.ajax(this);
                }
                console.log('ERROR! test');
                reject('retries exceeded');
            }
        });
    });
}

function run() {
    test().then(
        function() { console.log('finished ALL OK'); },
        function() { console.log('finished all ERROR'); }
    );
}
```

Comment: The only reason you would wrap something that already returns a promise in yet another promise is if the promise it returns isn't standards complaint enough to serve the purpose. Unless you're using a very old version of jquery, that isn't the case here.

Comment: to be fair, very old versions of jquery are still quite common

Comment: problem i have with stackoverflow in general; it's hard to know what the target is so i find myself falling back on older methodology in answers more often than not.  your criticism about appropriate use of extra promises though is valid and well taken.